# Using boost library in Julia with Cxx.jl on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, julia

I'm using Cxx with Julia 1.3.1 to use a function of the boost library, it works properly on Linux after the installation of such library, but in Windows i have never make it work. This is the module i wrote:

```
module Airyzero

#Returns zeros of Airy's function

using Cxx;
export airyzero
cxx""" 
    #include<iostream>
    #include <boost/math/special_functions/airy.hpp>
    #include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
    typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 float_type;
    """

cxx"""
    double airyzero1(int y) {
    return boost::math::airy_ai_zero<double>(y);
    }
    """

    airyzero(ind) = @cxx airyzero1(ind)

end
```

So i can use the function `airy_ai_zero` from boost as `airyzero` in my code. I need that works also in Windows because none of the computers of my lab uses Linux (neither my collegues).

Comment: I don't know much about special functions, but maybe the [respective implementations in SpecialFunctions.jl](https://juliamath.github.io/SpecialFunctions.jl/stable/functions_overview/#[Airy-and-Related-Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9)-1) is enough?

Comment: @phipsgabler No, precisely because i want to calculate the n-th zero of the Airy function, initially i also checked if this function was implemented in SpecialFunctions.jl, but that is not the case, so in order to not reinvent the wheel, i looked for an implementation in GSL.jl or in another language and i found that function in the boost library.

Answer (score 1):

I added to the header directory the path where boost was installed:

```
if Sys.iswindows()
   const pathboost = "C:\\boost_1_73_0";
   addHeaderDir(pathboost,kind=C_System);
end
```